# Read excel file and concatenate strings inside cells in java

Tags: java, excel, arraylist

I have an excel file with 3 columns. I can read the cells and put it in arraylist. However, I am stucked in concatenating the strings inside the cells. Here's what I have tried.

```
String str = null;
for (int i = 1; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
    List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) list.get(j);
        System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
        cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().concat(str);
        if (j < list.size() - 1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }                
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
int norows = sheetData.size() - 1;
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Number of Rows: " + norows);
```

I would like to seek assistance. Cheers!

Comment: You seem to have a **lot** of casting, which you should not have. For example, why are you casting something to a `List`? One should never see a rawtype in modern Java without very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

initialize a string above your loop. 
then keep adding to the string using

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

s.append(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
```